# In VueJS, how can I send an event to a custom directive

Tags: vue.js

I am using custom directive in Vuejs to render a pie chart (using chart.js), and I would need to notify the chartjs object to add a new segment or to remove a segment depending on the user's action.

While I can wrap the custom directive in a component so that it can receive events, how can the component communicate with the custom directive?

Comment: I think it's easier to wrap your pie chart in a component, without using custom directives. You can use directive dynamic attributes with you custom directive, but components have better event handling.

Comment: How do I use ChartJS as part of a component? There is a bit of JavaScript involved to initialize ChartJS, and where would those code go in the component?

Comment: the component has a lifecycle pretty much like a Vue instance. initialize anything in the `created()` hook.